# How to pass "this" to window setInterval

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have a function a:

```
function a() {
    this.b = 1;
    this.set = setInterval(function() {console.log(this.b);}, 200);
}
```

So when a.set() is called the anonymous function will be called. But this won't work as this at that time when the function is triggered points to the window object. Also it's not a good idea to use a.b as there may be multiple instances of a.

What is a good solution to this problem?

Comment: why don't you use `apply` or `call` https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Comment: @Deeptechtons - I don't think `apply` or `call` are any use for this problem, but perhaps you could explain what you had in mind in an answer?

Comment: @nnnnnn Question is definitely a candidate for "How do i change context inside function" sort of question. Which is solved using appy,or call. But might be overkill for this case.

Comment: @Deeptechtons Hmm good suggestion but definitely this problem clearly shouldn't be at that level.

Comment: @Deeptechtons - What I'm saying is that `.call` and `.apply` won't work here - you can't just add them inside the function passed to `setInterval` because by then `this` is already the wrong thing. `.bind` would work though, to set `this` in the function being passed to `setInterval`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Store a reference to `this`:

```
function a() {
    var self = this;
    self.b = 1;
    self.set = setInterval(function() {console.log(self.b);}, 200);
}
```

The anonymous function that you pass to `setInterval` has access to any variables in its containing scope, i.e., any local variables of `function a()`. The magic of JS closures keeps these variables alive even after `a()` has completed, and each invocation of `a()` gets its own closure.

Comment: Yea I've seen examples like that but that's exactly what makes me confused. Suppose "a" finishes before the event at 200ms gets triggered, the variable self seems that it should be destroyed at that time. If not, then when it would be destroyed? after the interval gets cleared?

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, an inner function has access to variables in the scope of its containing function _even after the containing function is finished_. In this case `setInterval` continues to hold a reference to the inner function so it can keep calling it even after `a()` has finished; until the interval is cleared that reference will stay alive and the variables will stay alive. Note that `a()` will _definitely_ finish before the interval gets triggered (no matter how short the interval) because JS runs on a single thread. Google "JavaScript closures" for more info.

Comment: This works when "this" var is a JS class (like in ReactJS), too, and not just a dom element.

Comment: Not sure why but inside the interval function self switches back to the window object?

Comment: @Shane - No it doesn't. But note that the value of `self` will depend on how `a()` is called, so e.g., if you just called it directly as `a()` then `this` (and thus `self`) will be `window` because that's how `this` works in non-strict mode.

Comment: Sorry my mistake; in my case i was using .apply, but but passed the inner (wrapped) object not the outer proxy object where the variables were.

Answer (score 12):

Since we have ES6 now, I think we need another answer here:

Use an arrow function:

```
function a() {
  this.b = 1;
  this.set = setInterval(() => {console.log(this.b);}, 200);
}
```

Arrow functions, opposite to normal functions, don't have a `this` context on their own. This means you have access to the outer `this`.

Comment: ES6 has reduced my syntax to almost nothing, once again!  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

This would be the cleanest solution, since most of the time you actually want to switch the this context for your consecutive method calls:

```
    // store scope reference for our delegating method
    var that = this;
    setInterval(function() {
        // this would be changed here because of method scope, 
        // but we still have a reference to that
        OURMETHODNAME.call(that);
    }, 200);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just save your `this` reference in some other variable, that is not overridden by the `window`-call later on. Later you can use that variable to reference he object you started with.

```
function a() {
    this.b = 1;
    var that = this;
    this.set = setInterval(function() {console.log(that.b);}, 200);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `bind` instead of saving `this` referance.

```
class Person {
    a() {
        this.b = 1;
        this.set = setInterval(function() {console.log(this.b);}, 1000);
    }

    c() {
        this.b = 1;
        this.set = setInterval((function() {console.log(this.b);}).bind(this), 1000);
    }
}

p = new Person()
p.a() //prints undefined
p.c() //prints 1
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you can simply:

```
function a() {
    var _this = this;
    this.b = 1;
    this.set = setInterval(function () {
      console.log(_this.b);
    }, 200);
}
```

Normally, we can also have a helper method [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to **fix** the `this` reference.

Answer (score 0):

This question is waay too old, but I did not like the solutions in here as the idea has mostly been about attaching the instance to something *public*.

Here is another, working idea:

The problem is that when calling as a callback from an interval, the scope is not inside `this`. However, you can kinda force it to be by defining a Function variable.

```
function a() {
  var localCallback: () => {
    // access `this` as you will
    console.log(this);
  };
  this.timer = setInterval( localCallback, this.saveInterval );
}
```

Hope this is helpful!