# setinterval not working to change image src

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

Wondering why the following code will not change my img src. The commented out example works just fine. And the alert triggers every 4 seconds. Replacing the src just wont work inside the set interval function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".samples_1_1").on("click", function(){
        alert('asdf');
        //$(this).attr("src", "../../static/results/samples_1_2.png");
        setInterval(function() {
          alert('alert 1');
          $(this).src("src", "../../static/results/samples_1_2.png");        
        }, 4000);
      });
    });
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10944004/how-to-pass-this-to-window-setinterval - this within setInterval refers to the window object. You need to pass an explicit reference to this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, in the second example you're using .src(), which does not exist. Use .attr() as before. Secondly, the `$(this)` keyword is now inside it's own function, making it undefined. You'll need to specify the element manually using  `$(".samples_1_1").attr("src", "../../static/results/samples_1_2.png");`

Comment: No, that's not it. I was just trying some things. My mistake. In the actual code it is the same, $(this).attr("src", "../../static/results/samples_1_2.png");

Comment: Sorry, yes I noticed the issue and have now revised my answer :)