# setInterval firing only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, setinterval

I know this may seem a duplicate but that's not the case here.
I'm trying to create a simple Slider with an OOP approach.
So here's what I've got so far:

```
function Slider(){
    this.totalSlides = 3;
    this.sliderImagesRoot = 'images/slider/';
    this.imagesLinks = [this.sliderImagesRoot + '1.png',this.sliderImagesRoot + '2.png',this.sliderImagesRoot + '3.png'];
    this.titles = ['State of the Art', 'Best staff kk', 'Toratos'];
    this.descriptions = ['First description, bla bla bla', 'werewr','Toraki']; 
    this.slideDelay = 1200;
    this.currSlide = 1;

    this.initSlider = function(){
        var createSlide = this.createSlide();
        var sliding = setInterval(function(createSlide){
            createSlide();
        }, 500);

    }

    this.createSlide = function(){
            alert("er");  
    }
}
```

I think it has something to do with passing into the function, any ideas?
This is the first time I try to implement OOP in JS by the way.

Comment: `this.createSlide` is undefined.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass "this" to window setInterval](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10944004/how-to-pass-this-to-window-setinterval)

Comment: This 'this' wasn't meant to be there, It was a leftover of something I was trying. I've just edited it, reread it without this.

Comment: @Xufox sorry I havent stumbled uppon this post, I'll go over it right now.

Comment: `createSlide` is a function parameter, but the function isn’t called with any parameter. Try `setInterval(function(createSlide){`…`}, 500, createSlideFunction);` where `createSlideFunction` is the declared and defined function.

Comment: setInterval is getting called properly the problem is with createSlide which is just undefined var. but you are using it as if it is a funtion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need create a separate constructor method for the object (`initSlider` in your code), the function `Slider` itself is the the constructor. Try something like this:

```
function Slider(){
    this.totalSlides = 3;
    this.sliderImagesRoot = 'images/slider/';
    this.imagesLinks = [this.sliderImagesRoot + '1.png',this.sliderImagesRoot + '2.png',this.sliderImagesRoot + '3.png'];
    this.titles = ['State of the Art', 'Best staff kk', 'Toratos'];
    this.descriptions = ['First description, bla bla bla', 'werewr','Toraki']; 
    this.slideDelay = 1200;
    this.currSlide = 1;

    var createSlide = function(){
            alert("er");  
    }
    var sliding = setInterval(function(){
        createSlide();
    }, 500);


}
```

and then you can construct the object like this:

```
var slider = new Slider();
```

Comment: so I guess its ok to remove this from evey variable right?

Comment: @JoeVox Not necessarily. If you want to be able to access those variables from outside the constructor, you need to store them in the object with `this`. So in essence, `this.totalSlides` makes `totalSlides` a public member of the object whereas `var totalSlides` makes it a private one.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from redneb should be what you need to proceed, but I'd like to point out something else that might be helpful.  Instead of a number of separate lists (`links`, `titles`, `descriptions`) and an independent counter, all of which need to be kept in synch, it would be much cleaner to store your data in a simple structure like this:

```
var slides = [
    {linK: '1.png', title: 'State of the Art', desc: 'First description,...'},
    {link: '2.png', title: 'Best staff kk',    desc: 'werewr'},
    {link: '3.png', title: 'Toratos',          desc: 'Toraki'}
];
```

Then you can derive `totalSlides` as `slides.length`, and when you go to use the `link` property, you can prepend `sliderImagesRoot`.

Comment: Yes, this approach is much more handy in many ways, thanks for pointing out :)

Answer (score 0):

setInterval callback is called as expected - however, inside the callback, you are trying to call a function passed as argument, and you are not passing anything, so it will be undefined.

If you run the code, you should see an error message:

`TypeError: createSlide is not a function`